# Setting the content of a std::stringstream with str(const char*) has strange consequences

Tags: c++, c++11, stringstream

I use `std::stringstream` extensively to generate code. I have run into some querious behavior when setting the content with the `str()` function followed by using the `operator<<`. Can someone explain this behavior to me. I would very much appreciate it - Thanks.

Example One:

```
std::stringstream ssa;
ssa.str("Setting string");
std::cout << ssa.str() << std::endl;
ssa << " adding to string";
std::cout << ssa.str() << std::endl;
```

Output:

> Setting string
>
> adding to string

Expected:

> Setting string
>
> Setting string adding to string

So after a bit of reading up on the documentation I found that I should set the open mode to `ios_base::ate`:

```
std::stringstream ssb(std::ios_base::ate);
ssb.str("Setting string");
std::cout << ssb.str() << std::endl;
ssb << " adding to string";
std::cout << ssb.str() << std::endl;
```

Output:

> Setting string
>
> Setting string

Again (or now) I would expect:

> Setting string
>
> Setting string adding to string

Why am I getting the results I am, and how do I get the result I want? E.i. Being able to set the initial `string` of a `stringstream` and the append to that `string` ?

I am aware that I can just set the content to the empty `string("")` and then only use the `<<operator`. This is in fact the workaround I am using. I just don't understand the observed behavior. And the workaround makes my code more messy.

Comment: For the second one, either do `std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate` or use a `ostringstream`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to set flag mode: `std::ios_base::out`.
This will work:

```
std::stringstream ssb(std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate);
ssb.str("Setting string");
std::cout << ssb.str() << std::endl;
ssb << " adding to string";
std::cout << ssb.str() << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
Setting string
Setting string adding to string
```

Comment: This is why I prefer using `std::istreamstream` and `std::ostringstream` instead of `std::stringstream`, then there is no confusion about the input/output mode.

Comment: Does reading from `str()` close and reopen the stream? Is that why `std::ios_base::ate` is needed to make this work? Without it, `<< " adding to string"` overwrites, rather than appends to, the data set by the previous `str("Setting string")`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, added to the answer, it does overwrite without ios_base::ate

Comment: But **why** does it overwrite? `ate` is applied when a stream is *opened* to seek to the end of existing content. So is `cout << ssb.str()` or `ssb << " adding ..."` re-opening the stream? But then wouldn't the existing content get wiped? That is what I don't understand. From all indications, reading `str()` just makes a copy of the current `rdbuf` content, so why is an extra seek-to-end needed afterwards? I cannot find any documentation on that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You can't open or close a stringstream. The `str()` method reinitializes the buffer by resetting the internal pointers. In particular, the *current pointer* is set to the beginning of the new buffer, which is why it is being overwritten by the next insertion. What `ate` does is keep the *current pointer* at the end of the buffer, so that each insertion appends to the stream.

Comment: Thank you. Would be nice if the documentation explained that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It can be found in the documentation for [`std::stringbuf::str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/str)

Comment: I already looked at that page, but do not see it say that reading from `str()` resets the buffer unless `ate` is used. But now I do see that it says how writing to `str()` initializes the pointers for subsequent reads/writes, and that `ate` allows subsequent output to be appended to the existing characters from a previous write to `str()`, but only in C++11 and later.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didn't mean that calling the zero-argument overload of `str()` resets the buffer pointers, but the `str(basic_string)` overload does. Also, see [LWG Issue 1448](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/lwg-defects.html#1448). Until C++11 it was implementation-defined what would happen when using `ate`.

Answer (score 12):

The default open mode for a `std::stringstream` object is `in | out`. Using a different mode overrides these options. Since the stream cannot be written to, the insertion operator cannot be used to write to the stream. This is why `str()` gives the same output twice.

You need to manually open the stream in output mode as well:

```
std::stringstream ssb("Setting string", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate);
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5215d8ba352eb80)

Alternatively, use an [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/), which initializes the internal `std::stringbuf` subobject with `out | mode`.

```
std::ostringstream("Setting string", std::ios_base::ate);
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f297857df8691ec4)

Comment: just out of curiosity, what's the point of having `streamstream` w/o `in` and `out` modes? Ok, I can imagine they can be added later. But why output operator doesn't throw an exception if `streamstream` doesn't have `out` mode? Ignoring silently doesn't look good

Comment: @AndyT Concrete `std::iostream` classes (`std::fstream` and `std::stringstream`) are built assuming you know how to initialize them. So it passes the mode to the underlying buffer as is, because it can't assume you want anything specific. I can't think of any use case for a stream that can't perform input or output. Also, streams don't throw exceptions by default but you may turn on exceptions using the `std::basic_ios::exceptions()` mask.